# Strange comments in Qt code

Tags: c++, qt

I see this comments `//! [0]` very often in Qt examples. What they mean?

Example (from a default MDI example):

```
//! [0]
exitAct = new QAction(tr("E&xit"), this);
exitAct->setShortcuts(QKeySequence::Quit);
exitAct->setStatusTip(tr("Exit the application"));
connect(exitAct, SIGNAL(triggered()), qApp, SLOT(closeAllWindows()));
//! [0]
```

Comment: this is [doxygen](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/) markings. It allows this tool to catch fragments of code which should be used in documentation as example. This way you have warranty that examples in documentation are compiling and working properly and are up to date. This fragment of [code you can see here in documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qapplication.html#closeAllWindows).

Comment: @MarekR: what?? Qt uses qdoc, not doxygen!

Comment: Thanks guys. This symbols can't be googled.